# Too much space between links in post menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, post-menu

In the 'menu' under the post, some extra space has been added (I presume accidentally) between the 'flag' link and the other options:

[image]

It looks like the separators are always shown, even though their corresponding options might be hidden. Here's how a full menu looks, and it's still evenly spaced:

[image]

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Is this [related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348027/289905) also being reviewed?

Comment: I'm assuming it's all the same issue?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no - it still isn't fixed yet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> the extra spaces
>
> once superfluously shown
>
> now rendered per spec

Comment: Thumbs up for keeping up an old tradition! It's been a while since I saw a haiku ...

Comment: While we're at it, I suggest changing the tooltip style of `follow` to match the tootips of other buttons.