# Bad spacing between ‘link’ and ‘full’

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

When looking at [this revision](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/154036/revisions), there is very little space between *link* and *full*:

[image]

Info:

- iOS 13.4.1
- Firefox 25.1

Comment: reproduced in Chrome 81.0.4044.138

Comment: Also reproduced in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: I guess [they moved it to the post menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347995/295232) ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been now been fixed across all sites.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: A screenshot where the "link" and "full" buttons are lacking space between them] | [image: A screenshot where the "link" and "full" buttons have space between them] |

I've asked the `full` link to follow social distancing guidelines in the future. Thanks for reporting this!