# "Show full diff" link is wrongly placed in the revision history of very long posts

Tags: bug, revisions-list, diff

When viewing the revision history of very long posts, only the changed parts of the posts are shown, while the rest is hidden. For example, in the revision history of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/67399/revisions), we see the following:

[image: "link" and "full" buttons are too close together]

Inside the red freehand "circle", we see two links: one link with text "link" that generates a link to this revision, and one link with text "full" that shows the full diff, and not only the changed parts. However, these links are so close together that they seem to be a single link with text "link full", which would seem to mean "get a link to the full version of this revision" or something like that.

This seems to happen only for very long posts, and seems to be network-wide (see an example on Spanish Language Meta [here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4383/revisions)).

Can this be fixed?

Comment: In fact, there is a separator among each item: `<span class="lsep">|</span>` only that the CSS of the `lsep` class needs some improvement so that it really shows as what it is, a `|`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Bad spacing between ‘link’ and ‘full’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348027/bad-spacing-between-link-and-full).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a screenshot of the wrong layout:

[image]

Which I easily fixed by duplicating the empty text node into these places:

[image]